# How Stop JWPlayer embedded within a Modal Dialog upon closing that Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jwplayer

I have modal dialog popups filled with various videos, played by JW Player.

I am using JQuery 1.7.1 with UI version 1.8.18 (both locally hosted), and am utilising the modal dialog widget in that package.

The problem is that closing the dialog, while the video is playing, does not send a STOP command to the player. Thus the dialog closes, but the audio keeps going. Only closing the entire window or tab of the browser will get it to shut off (just in IE, so far).

The JW Player Docs have [the following solution](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/contributors/nyboe/JW_API_xmpl_5-1-0-0.html):

```
onclick="player.sendEvent('STOP')"
```

which they bind to a local anchor tag.

My problem is that the close icon in the modal window is generated by the UI code itself - and I am loath to fiddle with it without guidance (I'm at JQuery pre-noob level -1).

So, to sum up, can anyone tell me how to achieve this `'STOP'` either by an external snippet, or by altering the UI coding itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `"close"` event of jQuery ui dialog:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   close: function(event, ui) { 
       player.sendEvent('STOP');
   },

   modal: true /* and so on with any other parameters you have */
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify - by `.selector` do you mean the actual class given to that link: `ui-dialog-titlebar-close`? Also would I place the `close:function...` with the other parameters of the dialog, or seperately, as you have here?

Comment: @Eamonn you didn't provide any code so this doesn't represent an integrated solution. To integrate with your code you would of course use appropriate `".selector"`, and yes, `"close"` is just another parameter like any other parameter you have.

Comment: Thanks, being a beginner makes me very wary of what I'm doing, so I had to check! :)

Comment: +1 also FYI the JavaScript in question can be found from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043240/jquery-modal-dialog-doubles-height-in-chrome-ie-safari-ignores-maxheight

Answer (score 1):

You can view their jQuery modal methods here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

```
    $( ".selector" ).dialog({
       beforeClose: function(event, ui) { ... }
    });
```

You will need to place the stop command inside the beforeClose function. This will then be called just before the modal is closed, there is also a 'Closed' function instead, which gets called after the modal is closed.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan - it seems that is the way to go, Esailija had the same solution below. I just am not certain where to put that snippet - in with the other modal settings, or as a separate function.

Comment: Can you paste the code that you have to create the modal? I can show you from there.

Comment: Sweet! here you go: `
.dialog({ autoOpen: false, title: Header, modal: true, maxHeight: 500, width:580, close: function(event, ui) { player.sendEvent('STOP'); } });`

Comment: The eventual code that worked: `.dialog({ close: function() { $(this).html(''); }, autoOpen: false, ...`. Otherwise the player would stop, the dialog would close, but the 'mother' page would reload and return to the site's index page.